# Java writing to a socket during a read causes deadlock

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

i'm having a problem with what looks like a deadlock.

It's a client/server app. The server has for every socket a thread to read and a thread to write.

Read thread takes client commands, processes it, puts results on a queue, write thread takes it off and writes it out.

Problem is if the read thread is blocking on readLine() and the write thread calls println() it blocks too, and the whole thing hangs. Stacktrace is provided and looks like println() tries to lock a resource that readLine() owns.

Can anyone help?

Simplified example:

ReadThread:

```
Socket s;
public void run() {
    BufferedReader sin = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
    while (true) {
        String line = sin.readLine();
        if (line == null) { break; }
        String response = "You sent us this: [" + line + "]";
        // add response to queue
    }
}
```

WriteThread:

```
Socket s;
public void run() {
        PrintStream sout = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream(), true);
        while (true) {
            String toWrite = getFromQueue();
            sout.println(toWrite);
            removeFromQueue(toWrite);
        }
}
```

The client's code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int portNumber = 51192;
    Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", portNumber);
    String cmd = "ThisIsATest";
    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream(), true);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
    out.println(cmd);
    String result = in.readLine();
    s.close();
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

stacktraces: http://pastebin.com/JnsHUFZn

full code of this example: http://pastebin.com/8RcbxgUw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have got the server-side `Socket` from a `SocketChannel`. The streams associated with such sockets are allocated by the `Channels` class, and they exhibit the behaviour you describe. The stack traces confirm it.

Use `java.net.Socket` directly, i.e. via a `java.net.ServerSocket` in the case of server code. There's no advantage to using `SocketChannel` or `ServerSocketChannel` in blocking  mode.